# Proving an inequality for a measure of two sets

Tags: measure-theory

The following is an exercise from Chapter 1 of Functional Analysis: Vol. I by Berezansky, Sheftel and Us.

> **Exercise 3.2.** Let $\mu$ be a measure on the algebra $\mathfrak R$ of subsets of $R$. Prove that, for all $A, B, C \in \mathfrak R$, the following equalities and inequalities take place:
>
> (a) $\mu(A \cup B) \leq \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ (semiadditivity of $\mu$);
>
> (b) $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu(A \cap B)$;
>
> (c) $\mu(A \triangle B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - 2\mu(A \cap B)$;
>
> (d) $|\mu(A) - \mu(B)| \leq \mu(A \triangle B)$;
>
> (e) $\mu(A \triangle B) \leq \mu(A \triangle C) + \mu(B \triangle C)$;
>
> (f) $$\begin{align*}
> \mu(A \cup B \cup C) = \mu(A)+\mu(B)+\mu(C) - \mu(A \cap B) - \mu(A \cap C)\\ - \mu(B \cap C) + \mu(A \cap B \cap C);
> \end{align*}$$
>
> (g) $|\mu(A \cup B) \times \mu(A \cap B) - \mu(A)\mu(B)| \leq \frac{1}{4}\mu^{2}(A \cup B).$

I have completed (a)-(f), but am a little stuck on (g). Here is my progress thus far:

> First, note that $$\begin{align*}
> \mu(A)\mu(B) &= (\mu(A \setminus B) + \mu(A \cap B))(\mu(B \setminus A) + \mu(A \cap B))\\
> &= \mu(A \setminus B)\mu(B \setminus A) + \mu(A \cap B)[\mu(A \setminus B) + \mu(B \setminus A)]\\
> &\quad + \mu^{2}(A \cap B)\\
> &= \mu(A \setminus B)\mu(B \setminus A) + \mu(A \cap B)[\mu((A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A))]\\
> &\quad + \mu^{2}(A \cap B)\\
> &= \mu(A \setminus B)\mu(B \setminus A) + \mu(A \cap B)\mu(A \triangle B) + \mu^{2}(A \cap B).
> \end{align*}$$
>
> Thus, $$\begin{align*}
> &\phantom{=s}|\mu(A \cup B)\mu(A \cap B) - \mu(A)\mu(B)|\\
> &= |\mu(A \cup B)\mu(A \cap B) - \mu(A \setminus B)\mu(B \setminus A)\\
> &\qquad - \mu(A \cap B)\mu(A \triangle B) - \mu^{2}(A \cap B)|\\
> &= |\mu(A \cap B)(\mu(A \cup B) - \mu(A \triangle B) - \mu(A \cap B)) - \mu(A \setminus B)\mu(B \setminus A)|\\
> &= |\mu(A \cap B)(\mu(A \cup B) - \mu((A \triangle B) \cup (A \cap B))) - \mu(A \setminus B)\mu(B \setminus A)|\\
> &= |\mu(A \cap B)(\mu(A \cup B) - \mu(A \cup B)) - \mu(A \setminus B)\mu(B \setminus A)|\\
> &= \mu(A \setminus B)\mu(B \setminus A).
> \end{align*}$$

I am especially having difficulty with introducing the factor of $\frac{1}{4}$. I do not have any idea how that would come about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a+b)^{2}\geq 4ab$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$.

So $4\mu (A\setminus B)\mu (B\setminus A)\leq [\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu (B\setminus A))]^{2}\leq [\mu (A \cup B)]^{2}$

Comment: Thank you. I found the proof for the first inequality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124518/1256533). We have $(a+b)^2 - 4ab = (a-b)^2 \geq 0$. Hence, $(a+b)^2 \geq 4ab$.